# Read from file in assembly

Tags: assembly

I am a beginner at Assembly, and am trying to figure out how to read from a file. I have looked at tutorials and sample code online, but all of them use a buffer that is defined in the .bss section. I have to convert my Assembly into bytecode though, so I cannot have the .bss section (or can I?).

On a side note, when opening the file, I am currently using:

```
mov ebx, file_name
```

but the same issue exists, where I do not want to define file_name in the .data section. Is this correct syntax?:

```
mov ebx, 'my_file.txt'
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned which OS your targetting, or which assembler you're using.

Comment: It would be Unix, and by assembler, do you mean AT&T vs Intel?

Comment: @avi1234 There are multiple flavours of syntax, so tell us which assembler you use (e.g. nasm or gas).

Comment: With `mov ebx, file_name` I'll assume Intel syntax. Likely NASM(or YASM)? Just a guess, but most likely on Linux

Comment: I am following the tutorial on TutorialsPoint, so I have been using NASM. Thanks for all the help

Comment: You first need to understand whether you will be reading the file through a library you are linking with or using System calls. For Systems calls, they are different for each OS and, furthermore, different between writing for 8,16,32 or 64 bit executables. Providing better context will get more attention.

Comment: What do you mean by "bytecode"? All assembly is ultimately…assembled into bytes, that are then executed as code by the CPU. Why are you so afraid of having a DATA section?

Comment: @FrankC. What do you mean by reading the file through a library? If the file is stored on my computer, for example, which category would it fall under?

Comment: @CodyGray I was looking to use https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm to convert the Assembly code, but it said I cannot have periods in the code? That's why I thought it would not be allowed to have a .data section.